# How to add siren sound to Blink Amazon camera security system?

Tags: security, camera, system, blink, siren

In the past Blink product could be equipped with a siren module

[image]

Today it's integrated into one of their camera products.

https://blinkforhome.com/.

[image]

There is another way to go around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found, is to use your phone ( in my case Android ) has a siren gadget.
I changed the camera notification tone to a siren tone, using the Android apps settings screen.
You can install any ringtone app to support this feature.
Enjoy :)